# What happens if a 26 AWG wire is connected to a 20A switching power supply that is connected to a stepper motor only using 1.5A?

Tags: arduino, power, motor, switch-mode-power-supply, stepper-motor

Basically the title but if a a 26 AWG wire is connected to a 20 amp power supply but a stepper motor is only pulling 1.5 A will the wire burn or not.

Comment: Nothing of note will happen.

Comment: ... until you have a short on the motor and then your cable will get very hot.

Comment: look at voltage of power supply and overall resistance of load.  Amp specs are usually a max ratings and dont tell what happens in a specific scenario.  motors dont "pull" amps so much as voltage pushes amps through them.

Comment: Absolutely nothing will happen.  Put a stepper motor driver into the equation and you will possible get rotation.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on plastic insulation, AWG 26 will rise 30'C to 60'C with 1.3A according to AWG tables.

Due to length and wire diameter, wire inductance will increase to about 1uH/m with R= 134 mΩ/m.

This series wire alone a has a limited risetime of T=L/R = 1 uH / 134 mΩ or 7.4ms.

It adds to damping the PWM but subtracts greatly  from power loss in wires getting to the motor.  **Use many in parallel or stranded wire..**

For every 3 AWG number changes, the power loss or rise is 50% or 2x.
so 26-6=AWG20 would be 4 times better  \$\Delta T=30'C /4=7.5'C\$

If your total power is 12V *1.5A= 18W and you want the wire to be 99% efficient what should the total wire resistance be? \$R=P/I^2\$

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your supply capability doesn't matter.

If you have a power supply that is rated for 100A, it doesn't mean that it must provide 100A at all times. It's only a maximum. The load will pull as much as it needs. If your motor pulls 1.5A, then any supply with rating over 1.5A can do it. It will pull 1.5A.

The wire is another matter. There are different lookup tables that can allow you to estimate how much current wires of different diameter can pass, give it a try in some search engine. I found numbers slightly different than Tony, where AWG 26 has a rating of 1A.

[source of questionable quality here](https://www.jst.fr/doc/jst/pdf/current_rating.pdf)

But both our numbers, I'd say, suggest that 1.5A is a little too much for a single wire. You don't want to risk it, because it's, well, playing with fire. In worst case, quite literally.

The best thing to do will be to have 2-3 of these wires in parallel. Also, don't forget about return current, the current goes to the motor and back, so all connections must be *thicc*.

EDIT (can't add comment for some reason, add comment button doesn't work):

Parallel wires means you have two wires that start at the same point and end at the same point. And in this case they should be of the same length so their resistances are around the same and they share current as evenly as possible.

So if you have 1 wire, it connects points A and B. And now you will have 2 wires, both of them connect A and B, so they go literally in parallel to each other. Double wire.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Also can you guide me how would I use the wires in parrarel?

Comment: What is "thicc?"

Answer (score 0):

As someone else has noted, the use of interconnect wiring that is not capable of carrying the full fault current suggests that you should have a fuse or poly fuse in there, rated at the maximum safe current for the weakest link.